# Adding a mergefield as a token in basicsharp C# basic interpreter class library

Tags: c#, basic

Hi I am currently using Basic Sharp link: https://github.com/Timu5/BasicSharp
This is a basic language interpreter. We need to use merge fields in this code to replace mergefields with values.

For example:

```
IF [Clients.Name] = "Patrick" THEN

#Do something

ENDIF
```

The merge field needs to be setup as a token and then it's value parsed and replaced depending on its type.

so the above would be parsed and replaced like so:

```
IF "Patrick" = "Patrick" THEN
#Do Something
ENDIF
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I am available to go through this in more detail on a screenshare if this would help!

**What I have tried:**

I have tried the below code from the interpreter, as it parses line by line. This is one of the requirements. As this can be used in the DO While loop, where the database value can change:

```
void Line()
    {
        string lineText = GetLine();
       // MessageBox.Show(lineText);
        string regularExpressionPattern = @"\[.*?\]";

        string inputText = lineText;
        int intVal = 0;
        double Double123 = 0.00;
        Regex re = new Regex(regularExpressionPattern);
        string finalvalue = "";
        Run_Code rc = new Run_Code();
        rc.case_ref = case_ref;
        rc.CaseTypeIndex = CaseTypeIndex;
        foreach (Match m in re.Matches(inputText))
        {
            inputText = inputText.Replace(m.Value,'"' + rc.getDBValue(m.Value.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "")) + '"');
        }
        // skip empty new lines
        while (lastToken == Token.NewLine) GetNextToken();

        if (lastToken == Token.EOF)
        {
            exit = true;
            return;
        }

        lineMarker = lex.TokenMarker; // save current line marker
        Statment(); // evaluate statment

        if (lastToken != Token.NewLine && lastToken != Token.EOF)
            Error("Expect new line got " + TranslateToken(lastToken.ToString()));
    }
```

Comment: Do you realize that in your example you are using curly brackets `{}` while in your regex you are searching for square brackets `[]` ?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comment, i should've mentioned that merge fields are shown surrounded by [] instead of {}, will update now. Would you be able to help with this?

Comment: What you are doing with the regular expression is the way to go (I would use `"\[[^\[\]]*\]` instead to avoid `.*` as it is error prone but your regex is correct) and seems to be ok, BUT, inputText isn't used anywhere, maybe that's your problem?

Comment: I think you may be right with that, would you be free for a screenshare to go through this?